# Java: return 2D Array with very varying entry lengths as formatted string

Tags: java, arrays, string

I want to write a `toString` method for a Matrix class where I need to return a formatted string which contains the matrix. The entries in the matrix are very different in length so just separating the entries with a `TAB` doesn't the trick. Right now I have the following:

```
public String toString(){
    String str = "";
    for(int i=0;i < _dim[0];i++){
        for(int j=0;j < _dim[1];j++){
            str += this.values[i][j] + "\t" + "\t";
        }
        str += "\n";
    }
    return str;
}
```

Which gives me something like this.

```
3.2004951E7     -1.591328E7     17839.0     
-35882.0        17841.0     -20.0       
1794.0  -892.0         1.0
```

Is there a way to print these properly aligned without knowing in advance how long each entry is going to be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to print these properly aligned without knowing in
>   advance how long each entry is going to be?

I don't think there is any built-in library function available which can do such things
for us. We will have to make our own formatting such as, using: `%-xs`:

1. Create an one dimensional array: `maxWidth[col]` to find the maximum width of each column: the column size is equal to the number of column of the 2D array.
2. Visit the 2D array to find the maximum width of each column
3. create the formatting string for each column using `"%-"+maxWidth[col]+"s "`, where `-` after the `%` specifies formatting for left-justified.
4. Please check out the [formatting Numeric Print Output](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) for more details.

The sample code:

```
   String data[][] = {{3.2004951E7+"" , -1.591328E7+"",  17839.0+"" },
                      {-35882.0 +"" , -17841.0+"",  -20.0+"" }};


    int col = data[0].length;
    int row = data.length;

    int maxWidth[] = new int[col];

    for(String[] rowD : data)
     for(int i=0; i< col; i++)
     {
         if(maxWidth[i] < rowD[i].length())
             maxWidth[i] = rowD[i].length();
     }

    String format = "";

    for(int x : maxWidth)
        format += "%-"+(x+2)+"s ";

    format +="%n";

    System.err.println(format);

    for(String[] rowD : data)
    {
        System.out.printf(format, rowD);
    }
```

**Output:**

```
3.2004951E7   -1.591328E7   17839.0   
-35882.0      -17841.0      -20.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.format()` if you know the length of your longest String, let's call it `maxLength`.

```
public String toString(){
  String str = "";
  for(int i=0;i < _dim[0];i++){
      for(int j=0;j < _dim[1];j++){
        String value = String.valueOf(this.values[i][j]);
        str += String.format("%1$-" + (max-value.length()) + "s", " ") + value + "\t";
      }
    str += "\n";
  }
  return str;
}
```

Comment: But isn't the problem is **not knowing** the length?

Comment: you could find it first before creating the string

Comment: Ok. I first went through the array and got the maximum length of an entry with this statement inside the same two for loops:  
`length = String.valueOf(this.values[i][j]).length();  if (length > maxLength) maxLength = length;`  

and substituted `(max-value.length())` with `(maxLength)` which made it better but not perfect.